# Android Activity losing GL Context

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I have spent a few days reading and implementing various solutions to this and so far absolutely none of them work, so I am now thinking I have a different problem here.

When my device (Nexus 4) rotates or I leave the app before returning, the screen goes to the clear-colour of my GL view.

This uses NDK to do the OpenGL drawing.

I have one class, the MainActivity (Pastebin as quite sizable):
http://pastebin.com/ZP2hhxpA

(I did recreate the GLSurfaceView class as recommended by some solutions, didn't solve the problem)

If I start up the app and not rotate/leave it, everything is fine, I have a nice 3D graphics engine I have ported to Android and it works brilliantly until the device is rotated, according to people the context is simply lost.

What my native code does is call GLES 2.0 functions, doesn't do any context creation, doesn't do anything special, if I wanted to I can move the functions into Android's Java side in the onDrawFrame() and I still have this problem.

I have tried:
 - Setting the GLSurfaceView to not lose context on pause (Changes nothing)
 - Recreating GLSurfaceView as a new class (Changes nothing)
 - Disabling rotation (Not a valid solution, problem is still there when pausing)

A lot of people say the solution is load the textures and create the shader in the onSurfaceCreated() method, which is exactly what I am doing. This isn't a case of textures not loading, when using a shader that has no textures the screen still goes white, it's as if my object disappears.

I cannot figure out how to retain the context manually, I have failed to find any sample code and while this problem is well known and documented there seems to be little code for actual solutions.

I have noted one warning message, when rotating the device the Nexus 4 GPU driver reports either of these two errors (Changes with each relaunch of app) within the glDrawArrays() call each time the screen is rotated:

```
<core_glHint:84>: GL_INVALID_ENUM
<gl_draw_error_checks:575>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

This leads me to presume that my vertex arrays and invalid for the current context, however I can guarantee that the vertex arrays are destroyed and rebuilt on the onSurfaceCreated() call within the activity.

On a Nexus 7 every once in a while after rotating/pausing it will come up with the error:

```
call to OpenGL ES API with no current context
```

So it's certainly a context problem.

I'm pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: Did you hook up the `onPause()` and `onResume()` between the activity and the `GLSurfaceView`?

Comment: I have pasted my code onto the paste bin which has these methods set, they are definitely called at the correct times.

Comment: GLSurfaceView explicitly destroys the context when the app is paused.  You can try to override this with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(boolean) , but it's usually easier to just tear everything down and bring it back up on pause/resume.

Comment: Tearing it down and bringing it back is what I am already doing, I am still getting GL errors about missing contexts.

I have found that if I add a delay of 1 second during the creation I can reliably recreate everything perfectly fine, without the delay I get the context problems. Weird considering this app has no multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code, you are destroying the context when the app pauses.
Refer to renderer.Destroy()

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (renderer != null) {
        glSurfaceView.onPause();
        renderer.Destroy(); // Deconstruct the native objects + gl textures
    }
}
```

I would try to remove that call, since otherwise the glSurfaceView will have a reference to a renderer which is destroyed.

Comment: renderer.Destroy() is my own method for dealing with the NDK shutdown, it doesn't touch the context

Comment: Well your resources will be destroyed looking at your comment. So you would be using invalid or no resources

Comment: The OpenGL resources are destroyed, am I not supposed to do this? I was under the impression that the GL handles are not transferred between contexts